# how to update table or model on button click

Tags: odata, sapui5, hana

I have one table on hana DB, exposed it as xsodata service

```
service  { 
"schema"."table" as "OrderItem";
}
```

showing the in ui5 app as

```
var Model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("../../services/myexp.xsodata/OrderItem", false);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(Model,'myitem');

var oTemplate = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
        cells : [
            new sap.m.Text({text : "{myitem>Component}"}),
            new sap.m.Text({text : "{myitem>Customer}"}), 
            new sap.m.Text({text: "{myitem>Required Date}"}),
            new sap.m.Text({text : "{myitem>Status}"})
        ]
    });

oTable.bindItems("myitem>/d/results", oTemplate);
```

Working fine
[image]

Now as in image I have two buttons added at the page footer as

```
footer: new sap.m.Bar({
    contentRight: [
        new sap.m.Button({text: "Accept",type: sap.m.ButtonType.Accept}),
        new sap.m.Button({text: "Reject",type: sap.m.ButtonType.Reject})
    ]
})
```

now my question is how to update the Status column on click of any button, say If i press accept status will change to accepted and same with reject. (updating the model. I guess hana table will automatically update as tyhe table is expossed as odata model)

note this table will have only one row.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to update data on the server or just the data you have in the model ?

Answer (score 0):

you don't get that kind of functionality with a JsonModel. Only using OdataModel you will get that kind of functionality out of the box.

J.

Comment: Ok lets say I use odata model in place of jsonmodel, but how to add the update functionality to a button not in the table row, its in the page footer.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function from the button's press event:

```
footer: new sap.m.Bar({
    contentRight: [
            new sap.m.Button({
text: "Accept",
type: sap.m.ButtonType.Accept, 
press: oController.pressAcceptButton}),
            new sap.m.Button({
text: "Reject",
type: sap.m.ButtonType.Reject})
        ]
})
```

and in the controller, respond to this press event:

```
pressAcceptButton: function(oEvent){
//perform transaction and refresh models
}
```